# I want to install and run slurm on ubuntu on single computer

Tags: hpc, slurm

I want to install and  run slurm  on ubuntu on single computer. I just want to run some sample examples.

Is this possible ?? and if possible how can i install and run it. 
I have searched on google but it is not working till now. 
Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found this a useful tutorial for setting up a small Ubuntu Slurm cluster:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2404746

Answer (score 0):

Here you have brief instructions for exactly what you are asking.
https://drtailor.medium.com/how-to-setup-slurm-on-ubuntu-20-04-for-single-node-work-scheduling-6cc909574365

Disclaimer: I didn't try it myself yet.